# Latitude Longitude from Free-form Address or Partial address lookup api

Tags: here-api

For converting an address to latitude longitude
 1. I have tried Nominatim.API from NuGet packages (Open Street Map)- it gives 10 results for the house number and postcode in its forward search API
 2. Google geocoder- it might be good but it has a free limit
Hence, choosing Here API's.

I am new to the here API and trying to use it in one of our test application in c# (using RestSharp library from NuGet packages). When I give below address for Partial address lookup or Free-form address lookup, I am not getting the exact latitude longitude values.
Address string for free-form: "201", "WOODHAM LANE", "ADDLESTONE", "KT15 3NR"
Address string for partial address lookup: "201", "Woodham Lane", "Addlestone", "United Kingdom"

The result JSON shows latitude, Longitude from Display position is: 51.351371,-0.4943669 and address is: 155, Woodham, Addlestone, KT15 3NJ.

Interestingly, in AdditionalData I can see Housenumberfallback=true and fallback value is 46.
On further analysis, I assumed the result house number 155 adding to this fallback value which is 46 is the actual house number already specified in either of the methods. Due to this, the position of such points on the map is not correct (the expected latitude longitude values are 51.34988152,-0.497168626 just what google gives).

Could you please suggest me if I have missed any point for the actual latitude, longitude values using Here API only.

Regards,
Kalyani

Comment: You use custom Nominatim server ?

Comment: To get the latitude, longitude from the address I tried using HERE APIs (most relevant to suit our needs), Nominatim.API from NuGet packages which is Open StreetMap API's- https://github.com/f1ana/Nominatim.API.

I am very much keen to know for the input sample provided above how could I achieve the exact correct Latitude Longitude (expected values) using HERE API

Comment: because nominatim is a public service, and many address reverse names are taken from wikipedia, public postal service, and bicycle routes , you need a add custom points, if you need check wich exact points has nominatim you can search in a big file csv gps points https://planet.openstreetmap.org/gps/

Comment: Okay, Many Thanks for your reply. I am keen on using HERE APIs for this task. Any idea what could be the reason for the difference in Latitude Longitude values? (in my original question, I have mentioned about HERE API's and why I chose to use HERE API's)

Comment: Please could anyone help with the above question using HERE API's
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/what-is.html

Answer (score 0):

For this address "201 Woodham Lane Addlestone KT15 3NR" HERE Geocoder API today give correct coordinate:

```
displayPosition: {
  latitude: 51.34997,
  longitude: -0.49725
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Is there any recent update (as this was not working previously)?